# Print string with variables in AWK

Tags: android, parsing, awk, adb, dumpsys

I am trying to parse android package list from phone.
Sample data is as shown below.

```
  Package [com.google.android.as] (9faf0bc):
    userId=10320
    pkg=Package{299f845 com.google.android.as}
    codePath=/system/priv-app/DevicePersonalizationServices
    resourcePath=/system/priv-app/DevicePersonalizationServices
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/system/priv-app/DevicePersonalizationServices/lib
    primaryCpuAbi=arm64-v8a
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    versionCode=4371429 minSdk=30 targetSdk=30
    versionName=R.3.sysimg.oem.325908743
    splits=[base]
    apkSigningVersion=0
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{299f845 com.google.android.as}
    flags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    privateFlags=[ PRIVATE_FLAG_ACTIVITIES_RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE_VIA_SDK_VERSION ALLOW_AUDIO_PLAYBACK_CAPTURE PRIVILEGED PRIVATE_FLAG_ALLOW_NATIVE_HEAP_POINTER_TAGGING ]
    forceQueryable=false
    queriesPackages=[]
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.google.android.as
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    timeStamp=2008-12-31 20:30:00
    firstInstallTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00
    lastUpdateTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00
    signatures=PackageSignatures{f91eb9a version:0, signatures:[], past signatures:[]}
    installPermissionsFixed=false
    pkgFlags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    install permissions:
      android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_ROUTING: granted=true
      android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW: granted=true
      << multiple lines >>
      android.permission.READ_DEVICE_CONFIG: granted=true
      android.permission.READ_OEM_UNLOCK_STATE: granted=true
    User 0: ceDataInode=0 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false distractionFlags=0 stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      gids=[3002, 3003, 3001]
    User 150: ceDataInode=0 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false distractionFlags=0 stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      gids=[3002, 3003, 3001]
  Package [com.google.android.gm] (a066ccb):
    userId=10230
    pkg=Package{9e45ca8 com.google.android.gm}
    codePath=/system/app/Gmail2
    resourcePath=/system/app/Gmail2
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/system/app/Gmail2/lib
    primaryCpuAbi=null
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    versionCode=62209002 minSdk=21 targetSdk=29
    versionName=2020.05.31.316831277.release
    splits=[base]
    apkSigningVersion=0
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{9e45ca8 com.google.android.gm}
    flags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP KILL_AFTER_RESTORE RESTORE_ANY_VERSION ]
    privateFlags=[ PRIVATE_FLAG_ACTIVITIES_RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE ALLOW_AUDIO_PLAYBACK_CAPTURE PRIVATE_FLAG_REQUEST_LEGACY_EXTERNAL_STORAGE HAS_DOMAIN_URLS PRIVATE_FLAG_ALLOW_NATIVE_HEAP_POINTER_TAGGING ]
    forceQueryable=false
    queriesIntents=[Intent { act=android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService }, Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://www.example.com/... }, Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://www.example.com/... }, Intent { act=android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService }]
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gm
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    usesLibraries:
      android.test.base
    usesOptionalLibraries:
      org.apache.http.legacy
    timeStamp=2008-12-31 20:30:00
    firstInstallTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00
    lastUpdateTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00
    signatures=PackageSignatures{c66d3c1 version:0, signatures:[], past signatures:[]}
    installPermissionsFixed=false
    pkgFlags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP KILL_AFTER_RESTORE RESTORE_ANY_VERSION ]
    declared permissions:
      com.google.android.gm.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT: prot=signature
      com.google.android.gm.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER: prot=signature
      << multiple lines >>      
      com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT: granted=true
      com.google.android.gms.permission.REQUEST_SCREEN_LOCK_COMPLEXITY: granted=true
      android.permission.WAKE_LOCK: granted=true
    User 0: ceDataInode=0 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false distractionFlags=0 stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      gids=[3003]
    User 150: ceDataInode=0 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false distractionFlags=0 stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      gids=[3003]
```

To parse data in AWK, I am using the command as under

```
dumpsys package | awk '/^[ ]*Package \[.*\] (.*)/ { i = index($0, "[") + 1; pkg = substr($0, i, index($0, "]") - i); } /[ ]*versionCode=/ /[ ]*versionName=/  /[ ]*firstInstallTime=/ /[ ]*lastUpdateTime=/ { { print "START PackageName=" pkg $0 " END"; pkg = ""; } }'
```

Output of the above command is as under

```
versionCode=4371429 minSdk=30 targetSdk=30    versionName=R.3.sysimg.oem.325908743    firstInstallTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00START PackageName=com.google.android.as    lastUpdateTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00 END    versionCode=62209002 minSdk=21 targetSdk=29    versionName=2020.05.31.316831277.release    firstInstallTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00START PackageName=com.google.android.gm    lastUpdateTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00 END
```

The problem is the order of data output. The expected output should be in order between START and END as being printed. I am not able to get the structured data as desired.
Please advise.

Comment: I recommend you to post your expected result. Easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2**

To output data for one package on one line, delimited by tabs,
append `| paste - - - -` to the `awk` command, i.e. one dash for each of
the 4 attributes selected.
[`paste`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html)
has a `-d` option to specify a delimiter.

Or you could use my original answer which did that - with attributes in specified order - if you passed `-v isheader=""` to `awk`.

**EDIT**

Second attempt, perhaps I misread:

```shell
dumpsys package | awk '
/^[ ]*Package \[/ { 
    pkg = substr($2,2,length($2)-2)
}
/^[ ]*(versionCode|versionName|firstInstallTime|lastUpdateTime)=/ { 
    print "START PackageName=" pkg $0 " END"
}
'
```

or, as a one-liner:

```shell
dumpsys package | awk '/^[ ]*Package \[/ { pkg = substr($2,2,length($2)-2); } /^[ ]*(versionCode|versionName|firstInstallTime|lastUpdateTime)=/ { print "START PackageName=" pkg $0 " END"; }'
```

Output:

```
START PackageName=com.google.android.as    versionCode=4371429 minSdk=30 targetSdk=30 END
START PackageName=com.google.android.as    versionName=R.3.sysimg.oem.325908743 END
START PackageName=com.google.android.as    firstInstallTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00 END
START PackageName=com.google.android.as    lastUpdateTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00 END
START PackageName=com.google.android.gm    versionCode=62209002 minSdk=21 targetSdk=29 END
START PackageName=com.google.android.gm    versionName=2020.05.31.316831277.release END
START PackageName=com.google.android.gm    firstInstallTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00 END
START PackageName=com.google.android.gm    lastUpdateTime=2008-12-31 20:30:00 END
```

You were very close but `||` operators were missing between regexes, and `pkg` was reset to an empty string in the second awk pattern.

---

(Original answer follows)

The output you posted is basically a conf file with key-value
pairs but repeated for each 'Package' section.

The following `awk` script collects the values for attributes given
in the `att` variable in an associative array (`Val`) and prints the
array as tab-separated values (TSV) in one line per section, in the
specified order.

`OFS` is `awk`'s output field separator. Like the `att` and `isheader`
variables `OFS` can be specified on the `awk` command line.
It defaults to tab here but can be overridden with `ofs="\\n"` or
`ofs="|"` for example.

Use with `mawk` or `gawk` as:

```shell
: ${ofs=$(printf '\t')}
dumpsys-command |
awk -v OFS="${ofs}" -v isheader="" -f '/path/to/script' |
while IFS="${ofs}" read -r pkg vcode vname dt1st dtupd
do  printf '%s\n' '# -----' \
    "Package: ${pkg}" \
    "Version code: ${vcode}" \
    "Last update: ${dtupd}"
done
```

```
BEGIN {
    regexSectionStart = "^ *Package "
    keyvalsep = "="
    if ( !att )
        att="pkg  versionCode  versionName  firstInstallTime  lastUpdateTime"
    split(att, Att, "  ")
    for ( i in Att )
        Idx[Att[i]] = i
    if ( isheader )
        emitArr(Att)
}
$0 ~ regexSectionStart {
    emitArr(Val)
    for ( i in Val )
        delete Val[i]
    next
}
{
    key = substr($1, 1, -1+index($1,keyvalsep))
    if ( key in Idx )
        Val[Idx[key]] = substr($0, 1+index($0,keyvalsep))
}
## Print array in index order, skip if empty
function emitArr(V,  i,s) {
    for ( i in V ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=length(V); i++ )
            s = s (i==1 ? "" : OFS) V[i]
        print s
        return
    }
}
END{ emitArr(Val); }
```

Output from `awk` script (`isheader="x"`):

```
pkg versionCode versionName firstInstallTime    lastUpdateTime
Package{299f845 com.google.android.as}  4371429 minSdk=30 targetSdk=30  R.3.sysimg.oem.325908743    2008-12-31 20:30:00 2008-12-31 20:30:00
Package{9e45ca8 com.google.android.gm}  62209002 minSdk=21 targetSdk=29 2020.05.31.316831277.release    2008-12-31 20:30:00 2008-12-31 20:30:00
```

Output from shell script:

```
# -----
Package: Package{299f845 com.google.android.as}
Version code: 4371429 minSdk=30 targetSdk=30
Last update: 2008-12-31 20:30:00
# -----
Package: Package{9e45ca8 com.google.android.gm}
Version code: 62209002 minSdk=21 targetSdk=29
Last update: 2008-12-31 20:30:00
```

Comment: Hi @urcodebetterznow, thank you for the script, but I need a single line solution as I have to pass it along with a command. I am trying to integrate the above solution in windows so I have to execute the command on remote device only.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: see my updated answer; I think this does what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @urcodebetterznow, Almost what I need, but we are getting 8 rows output for 2 packages. Only 2 rows were expected. I am trying a post operation. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: @AnkitSharma: My answer is now updated suggesting use of the `paste` command.

Comment: Thanx again, @urcodebetterznow, I'll definitely mention you, if the project gets completed.

Comment: No need to credit me but if you found my answer useful consider 
[accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.